# JavaFX 2.2 MouseEvent in SubScene does not work properly

Tags: javafx-2, mouseevent

I am trying to get this to work for sometime and I cannot figure out what wrong with my code.  This leads me to believe there is some issues in SubScene Mouse listener.  Any idea is appreciated.

Basically I have a scene contains two subscenes, one for the toolbar and one for the floor which has bunch of lines making it looks like tiles.  I added mouse listeners so that when I clicked on the floor and move the mouse, the camera will move as if I am walking on the floor.
The problem is that the floor only recognize mouse event when I clicked on the intersection between the first vertical and the first horizontal line (yup, took me a while to figure that out).  Mouse event should occur everywhere on entire floor.

Here is the code.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.PerspectiveCamera;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.SceneAntialiasing;
import javafx.scene.SubScene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FloorTest extends Application {

double mousex, mousey;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Hello World!");
        }
    });

    Group bargroup = new Group();
    SubScene bar = new SubScene(bargroup, 300, 20, true, SceneAntialiasing.DISABLED); 
    bargroup.getChildren().add(btn);

    Group floorgroup = new Group();
    SubScene floor = new SubScene(floorgroup, 300, 250, true, SceneAntialiasing.DISABLED);
    ObservableList<Node> list = floorgroup.getChildren();
    for(int i = 0; i < (300/20); i++)
    {
        double x = i * 20;
        Line line = new Line(x, 0, x, 250);
        list.add(line);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < (250/20); i++)
    {
        double y = i * 20;
        Line line = new Line(0, y, 300, y);
        list.add(line);
    }

    PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera(false);
    camera.setNearClip(0.1);
    camera.setFarClip(10000.0);
    camera.setTranslateZ(-200);
    floor.setCamera(camera);

    floor.setOnMousePressed((MouseEvent event) -> {
        mousex = event.getSceneX();
        mousey = event.getSceneY();
    });

    floor.setOnMouseDragged((MouseEvent event) -> {
        double x = event.getSceneX();
        double y = event.getSceneY();
        camera.relocate(camera.getLayoutX() + (x - mousex), camera.getLayoutY() + (y - mousey));
    });



    Group mainroot = new Group();
    mainroot.getChildren().addAll(floor, bar);        

    Scene scene = new Scene(mainroot, 300, 250, true);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

/**
 * The main() method is ignored in correctly deployed JavaFX application.
 * main() serves only as fallback in case the application can not be
 * launched through deployment artifacts, e.g., in IDEs with limited FX
 * support. NetBeans ignores main().
 *
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that setting the `subscene.setPickOnBounds(true)` should help in proper recognition of the mouse events for the whole subscene. Tested with javafx 8.

Comment: Thanks. This does make it work.  I don't understand why you have to do this to make mouse to work.  If the subscene requires this to work with mouse listener, may be it should be included in the setOnMouseXXX

Answer (score 0):

Please try using `scene` instead of `floor` variable in event handlers

Example:

```
scene.setOnMousePressed((MouseEvent event) -> {
    mousex = event.getSceneX();
    mousey = event.getSceneY();
});

 scene.setOnMouseDragged((MouseEvent event) -> {
        double x = event.getSceneX();
        double y = event.getSceneY();
        camera.relocate(camera.getLayoutX() + (x - mousex), camera.getLayoutY() + (y - mousey));
    });
```

That helps me

Comment: Thanks for response.  I was trying to make use of the benefit of subscene where I can have multiple subscenes in a scene and each of them can do different things.  I know using scene works.

Comment: I check some other answers for this. Maybe you have to use Mediator pattern. It's useful for that kind of communication.